# adding trailing slash to all special characters in preg

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, escaping

I want to add trailing slash for all the preg special characters..For example `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9c4PJTDljM` should be converted to `http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v\=i9c4PJTDljM`

I tried below code

```
echo preg_quote($url);
```

But it does not add trailing slash to backslash.and result is like this

```
http\://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v\=i9c4PJTDljM
```

Comment: [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote), second parameter for specifying the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$content = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9c4PJTDljM';
//With this pattern you found everything except 0-9a-zA-Z
$pattern = "/[_a-z0-9-]/i";
$new_content = '';

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($content); $i++) {
    //if you found the 'special character' then add the \
    if(!preg_match($pattern, $content[$i])) {
        $new_content .= '\\' . $content[$i];
    } else {    
        //if there is no 'special character' then use the character
        $new_content .= $content[$i];
    }   
}   

print_r($new_content);

?>
```

Output:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=i9c4PJTDlj